# How to create a shared folder as a domain admin in DC environment?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain-controller

how can I create a shared folder on the windows server? I am a domain admin with a full administrative right logged on from windows 10 domain-joined PC.

I was able to access the server drive using UNC path "\srvname\c$", however, I can't edit the share permission of the newly created folder even though I have administration rights.

Is there any other way for a domain admin to manage share folders? Are some tools similar to the Administrative Tool available to handle such?

Comment: you can't remotely manage the SHARE permissions of a share -- at least not via filesystem tools.

Domain admins probably shouldn't be logged onto workstations, FYI.

Comment: @Semicolon if that's the case then why are there administrative tools available in the first place anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Login to server with the share folder or use `mmc` console to open Shares on that server from your workstation and there edit Share and Access permissions. Best why to do that is to set share permissions full rights to Everyone grup and in access permissions to set who actually has witch  permissions.